# How to ensure every URL is being parsed in my Scrapy spider

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm attempting to crawl every page of recipe listings on a food blog, scrape the recipe URLs on each page, and write them all to a single .txt file. As my code currently stands, it works properly, but only for the first URL listed within `urls` inside the `start_requests` method.

I've added a `.log()` to check that `urls` does indeed contain all the correct URLs I'm trying to scrape from and when I execute Scrapy in command prompt, I get the following confirmation that they're there:

```
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=1
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=2
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=3
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=4
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=5
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=6
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=7
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=8
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=9
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=10
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=11
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=12
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=13
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=14
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=15
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=16
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=17
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=18
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=19
2019-01-31 22:16:17 [recipes] DEBUG: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=20
```

etc.

My current code:

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "recipes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = []
        for i in range (1, 60):
            curr_url = "https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=%s" % i
            self.log(curr_url)
            urls.append(curr_url)
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, "html.parser")
        page_links = soup.find_all(class_="post-summary")    
        for link in page_links:
            with open("links.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(link.a["href"] + "\n")
```

When I run the above, I get the following output written to links.txt:

```
https://pinchofyum.com/5-minute-vegan-yogurt
https://pinchofyum.com/red-curry-noodles
https://pinchofyum.com/15-minute-meal-prep-cauliflower-fried-rice-with-crispy-tofu
https://pinchofyum.com/5-ingredient-vegan-vodka-pasta
https://pinchofyum.com/lentil-greek-salads-with-dill-sauce
https://pinchofyum.com/coconut-oil-granola-remix
https://pinchofyum.com/quinoa-crunch-salad-with-peanut-dressing
https://pinchofyum.com/15-minute-meal-prep-cilantro-lime-chicken-and-lentils
https://pinchofyum.com/instant-pot-sweet-potato-tortilla-soup
https://pinchofyum.com/garlic-butter-baked-penne
https://pinchofyum.com/15-minute-meal-prep-creole-chicken-and-sausage
https://pinchofyum.com/lemon-chicken-soup-with-orzo
https://pinchofyum.com/brussels-sprouts-tacos
https://pinchofyum.com/14-must-bake-holiday-cookie-recipes
https://pinchofyum.com/how-to-cook-chicken
```

The links here are correct, but there should be 50+ more pages worth of them.

Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the code in your question is the one that generates that output? The output is made of links, but `class_="post-summary"` should match `<article/>` elements. In any case, try `for link in response.css('.post-summary a::attr(href)').getall()` instead of `for link in page_links`.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to make sure every page inside `urls` got scraped successfully and had links in it, if yes, then see this code below

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "recipes"
    urls = []

    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range (1, 60):
            curr_url = "https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=%s" % i
            self.log(curr_url)
            self.urls.append(curr_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=curr_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page_links = response.css(".post-summary")   
        if len(page_links)>0:
            del self.urls[response.url] #delete from URLS to confirm that it has been parsed
            for link in page_links:
                with open("links.txt", "a") as f:
                    f.write(link.a["href"] + "\n")


    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.log("Following URLs were not parsed: %s"%(self.urls))
```

What it does is that it appends all urls to be scraped into `self.urls` and once a URL is scraped and also has links in it, it removes from `self.urls`

And notice there is another method called `spider_closed`, it is executed only when scraper is finished, so it will print the urls which were not scraped or it didnt had links in it

Also, why using BeautifulSoup? simply use Python Scrapy's Selector class